# How to remove characters between single quotes in pl/sql using regexp_replace

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I would like to ask if there is someone who know how to remove the characters between single quotes in pl/sql using regexp_replace.

It would be like this.

```
The 'quick brown' fox jumps over the lazy dog.
--> The fox jumps over the lazy dog.

The 
'quick
 brown' 
fox jumps over 
'the lazy' dog.
--> The fox jumps over dog.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace('The ''quick brown'' fox jumps over the ''lazy'' dog', 
                 '''.*?''', '', 1, 0, 'm')
from dual
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The fox jumps over the dog
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/363)

Read more about `regexp_replace` [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

Comment: thanks for the quick response, it is working, however, it does not work when there are next lines between the words inside the single quotes. So I  could you please check if I did it correctly?
-- select regexp_replace('The ''quick brown'' fox jumps over the lazy dog', 
                    '''(.|'||chr(10) ||')*?''', '')
from dual

Comment: @jeraldgarayan for multilines you need to add additional 3 arguments: '1' - starting position to search in the string, '0' - number of occurrences to replace (zero means "all") and 'm' - multiline. I updated the answer and the demo above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "match param" option of 'n' to REGEXP_REPLACE to tell it to have the "match any character" character (the period) include a newline:

```
select regexp_replace('The ''quick 
brown'' fox jumps over the lazy dog', '''.*''', '', 1, 0, 'n')
from dual;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302